# Fetching Data from API using UseEffect

Tags: reactjs

I found one API which return a word, definition.

I want to display a word and definition and when the button is pressed it should refetch and show new word.

I wrote this code. But I can't make it work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I don't wanna use Axios or any library

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Button } from "react";

function RandomWord() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [refetch, setRefetch] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://rnd-word.vercel.app/word")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [refetch]);

  return (
    <>
      <div class="App">
        {isLoading ? (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        ) : (
          <span
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
            renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <p>{item.word}</p>
            <p>{item.defintion}</p>
          }
          />
        )}
      </div>
      <Button
        title="New Word"
        onPress={() => setRefetch(!refetch)}
        color="#e56b6f"
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default RandomWord;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` tag in reactjs only show normal text. Not like `FlatList` in the `react-native`. So you should use `map` to render like this:

```
{
    isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
    ) : (
        data.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
                <p>{item.word}</p>
                <p>{item.defintion}</p>
            </div>
        ))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `<span>` html element doesn't have attributes like `renderItem` or `keyExtractor`. When you want to render the `data` you should map it to JSX.

```
data.map((item, index) => 
  <div key={index}>
      <p>{item.word}</p>
      <p>{item.definition}</p>
  </div>
```

You can also directly call a function that fetches the data, you don't have to trigger another rerender that just triggers the fetch.

```
function fetchNextWord(){
  setLoading(true);
  fetch("https://rnd-word.vercel.app/word")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => setData(json))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}

useEffect(fetchNextWord, []); // Initial load
```

You can run this example snippet:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function RandomWord() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  function fetchNextWord(){
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("https://rnd-word.vercel.app/word")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }
  
  useEffect(fetchNextWord, []); // Initial load


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        {isLoading ? (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        ) : 
          data.map((item, index) => 
           <div key={index}>
               <p>{item.word}</p>
               <p>{item.definition}</p>
           </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={fetchNextWord}
        color="#e56b6f"
        >New Word</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<RandomWord />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would `console.log(json)` in your fetch. See if the data is being sent how you expect and populating data state correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're calling useEffect on changes to `refetch`, which is itself changed by the `setFetch` method, each time you call `onPress` on button

However, in a useState hook's state updation with respect to previous state, you have to specify in the updating function i.e. `setFetch` in this case that you want the new value obtained as a function of the previous value.

Hence, your change in code would be just this :

```
...
<Buttton
 onPress = setRefetch(prevRefetch => !prevRefetch)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";

let RandomWord = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [refetch, setRefetch] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://rnd-word.vercel.app/word")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [refetch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="App">
        {isLoading ? (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
            {/* whole fetch data */}
            {JSON.stringify(data)}
            {data.map((item) => {
              return (
                <Fragment>
                  <p> {item.word} </p>
                  <p> {item.definition} </p>
                </Fragment>
              );
            })}
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => setRefetch(!refetch)} color="#e56b6f">
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RandomWord;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).